# How is to implement action mode in fragment in androidx?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, androidx, android-actionmode

I have to implement action mode in fragment, but its gets nullpointer exception in action mode. I have tried so much but not gets any results, Please help me I am new in android. I have also tried startActionMode but not impact. I have wasted my time & searched lot of code not found any solution. Please help me

```
    public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;

private ActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;
private ActionMode actionMode;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_gallery);
    galleryViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    });

    final Button btnLoad = root.findViewById(R.id.load);
    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            enableActionMode(1, true );
        }
    });

    return root;
}

public void  enableActionMode(int position, boolean bool) {

    int count = 4;
    if(actionMode == null) {
        actionMode = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
    }

    if (count == 0) {
        actionMode.finish();
        actionMode = null;
    } else {

        actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(count));
        actionMode.invalidate();
    }
}

private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // getSupportActionBar().hide();
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        Log.d("API123", ""+item.getItemId());
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_delete:
                // delete all the selected rows
                //mode.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        //clear selections
        mode.finish();
        actionMode = null;
    }
    }
}
```

This is mycode, null pointer in actionmode. please help me i wasting my time. searching lot of, no result found